# setTabOrder по столбцам

Tags: qt5

Есть табличный лейаут с 12 текстовыми полями (четыре ряда по три поля). Как реализовать, чтобы по нажатию Tab переключение шло не по горизонтали, а по вертикали?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    setTabOrder(ui->gridLayout->itemAt(i)->widget(),
       ui->gridLayout->itemAt(i + 1)->widget());
```

Как сделать то же самое, только для столбцов?

Comment: [QWidget::setTabOrder](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setTabOrder), не?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Это понятно и я даже это написал в заголовке, а вот алгоритм не очень.

Comment: не представляю, что именно тут может вызвать затруднения...  код созданий виджетов/layout'а в студию...

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так можно:

```
int col = ui->gridLayout->columnCount();
int row = ui->gridLayout->rowCount();

for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
  for (int i = 0; i < row-1; i++) {
      setTabOrder (ui->gridLayout->itemAtPosition (i, j)->widget(),
                   ui->gridLayout->itemAtPosition (i, j+1)->widget());
  }
  if (i != col-1) {
    setTabOrder (ui->gridLayout->itemAtPosition (i,   row-1)->widget(),
                 ui->gridLayout->itemAtPosition (i+1, 0    )->widget());
  }
}
```

Проверка, что в `layout`'ах действительно `QWidget`'ы опущена.

Также порядок переключения можно задать прямо в дизайнере.